# Can oresol electrolyte rehydration relievers relieve a runny nose caused by sinusitis?

Tags: water, nose, hydration, ears-nose-throat-ent, vasomotor-rhinitis

I have had sinusitis since childhood, and it got worse after having covid 19, I used to have frequent runny nose, it made me very uncomfortable, but everything got better when I used oresol (rehydration electrolyte), why is that, can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Questions requesting personal medical advice are off-topic here. It would be inappropriate for anyone to attempt to address your health issues. Such questions should be taken to your personal physician who can examine you and access your full medical records. For more information, please see [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/805).